# Cubic spline interpolation in Julia with irregular grids

Tags: r, julia

I'm porting some code from R to Julia, and struggling with translating R's `spline` function. I need a Julia function:

```
function spline_j(x,y,xout)
```

that yields the same return as calling the R function:

```
spline(x,y,,"fmm",,,xout)
```

i.e. using the method of Forsyth, Malcolm and Moler, which is the default method in R.

My `x` and `y` are always 1-dimensional, but the points of `x` are not regularly spaced. That non-regularity seems to rule out using the pure-Julia `Interpolations` package as the [documentation](http://https//juliamath.github.io/Interpolations.jl/latest/convenience-construction/) states "presently only `LinearInterpolation` supports irregular grids".

The [`Dierckx`](https://github.com/kbarbary/Dierckx.jl) package supports irregular `x`, so a candidate for `spline_j` is:

```
using Dierckx

function spline_j(x, y, xout)
    spl = Dierckx.Spline1D(x, y)
    spl(xout)
end
```

which matches R's `spline` function if `method` is `"natural"`.

Is it possible to replicate R's `"fmm"` method in Julia?

Comment: You could check out this package, which has cubic splines: https://github.com/PumasAI/DataInterpolations.jl

Comment: Thanks Michael. Unfortunately `DataInterpolations` does not quite have what I'm after (at least on my first reading of the docs). But your comment made me think I need to learn how best to search for Julia packages. And that thought soon soon took me to a [post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-does-one-find-a-julia-package-for-a-specific-use/5379) on Julia discourse written by... you.

Comment: Ha ha - fortunately things have improved since then. https://pkg.julialang.org/docs/ is searchable now. I just searched there for "cubic spline" and it led me to https://github.com/nignatiadis/SmoothingSplines.jl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this PR https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/pull/238 (merged as [#243](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/pull/243)),  Interpolations.jl actually has a number of excellent monotonic spline  interpolation algorithms that support irregular grids, including Fritsch-Carlson (1980), Fritsch-Butland (1984), and Steffen (1990).

It doesn't seem to be reflected in the docs yet, but the options are visible in the following git [diff](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/pull/243/files#diff-92e3f2a374c9a54769084bad1bbfb4ff20ee50716accf008074cda7af1cd6149)

For example:

```
using Interpolations, Plots
x = sort(2*rand(10))
y = x.^2 .+ rand.()

itp = interpolate(x,y,FritschCarlsonMonotonicInterpolation())
xq = minimum(x):0.01:maximum(x)

plot(x,y, seriestype=:scatter, label="Data", legend=:topleft, framestyle=:box)
plot!(xq, itp.(xq), label="Interpolation")
```

[image: Fritsch-Carlson monotonic interpolation on irregular grid]

If you prefer different interpolation methods, you can also substitute
`FiniteDifferenceMonotonicInterpolation`,`FritschButlandMonotonicInterpolation`, or `SteffenMonotonicInterpolation` for `FritschCarlsonMonotonicInterpolation`.